# Integer being set to an arbitrary value

Tags: c++, directx

In a class to read in a .mtl file I have an integer value which stores the current index of the material being read in, and after a ifstream.getline() is being executed, the value is being set to a very large number. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
std::ifstream inf(fileName);
int mtlcount = -1;

if(!inf)
{
    std::cout << "File could not be opened";
    return 1;
}


while(!inf.eof())
{
    char line[40];
    inf.getline(line, 40);
//mtlcount set to a random value here
//more code
}
```

Edit:
The project is using DirectX 11, and mtlcount is just being set to a very high value that I don't know how it's being determined, so perhaps random wasn't the right word.

```
int Parser::readMtlFile(std::string fileName, std::vector<Material>* materials)
{
std::ifstream inf(fileName);
int mtlcount = -1;

if(!inf)
{
    std::cout << "File could not be opened";
    return 1;
}


while(!inf.eof())
{
    char line[40];
    inf.getline(line, 40);

    if(line[0] == 'n' && line[1] == 'e' && line[2] == 'w' && line[3] == 'm' && line[4] == 't' && line[5] == 'l')
    {
        mtlcount++;

        std::string mtlName;
        Material mtl;

        materials->push_back(mtl);

        int i = 7;
        while(line[i] != '\n' && i < 40)
        {
            mtlName += line[i];
            i++;
        }
        materials->at(mtlcount).name = mtlName;
    }

    if(line[0] == 'K' && line[1] == 'a')
    {
        float r, g, b;

        sscanf_s(line, "Ka %f %f %f", &r, &g, &b);

        materials->at(mtlcount).ambient = XMFLOAT4(r, g, b, 1.0);
    }

    if(line[0] == 'K' && line[1] == 'd')
    {
        float r, g, b;

        sscanf_s(line, "Kd %f %f %f", &r, &g, &b);

        materials->at(mtlcount).diffuse = XMFLOAT4(r, g, b, 1.0);
    }

    if(line[0] == 'K' && line[1] == 's')
    {
        float r, g, b;

        sscanf_s(line, "Ka %f %f %f", &r, &g, &b);

        materials->at(mtlcount).specular = XMFLOAT4(r, g, b, 1.0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We need to see where you use `mtlcount`

Comment: To start with, don't use `while (!inf.eof())`, it will not work as you expect it to. The reason being that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you read from beyond the end of the file. That means your loop will loop once to many. Instead to e.g. `while (inf.getline(...))`.

Comment: As for your problem, how do you determine that `mtlcount` have a random value?

Comment: The code you posted would not exhibit this problem. Please post actual code that we can reproduce the problem with, or this cannot be answered.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah, thanks, once I've fixed this I'll take that into account

Comment: Note that using `.eof()` for loop control is **always** wrong! You **always** need to test **after** reading whether the read was successful! Whether that is related to your problem, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [this reference for `sscanf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkx076cy.aspx), as you are not using it correctly. That means your code have *undefined behavior*, and that means whatever behavior you have might be because of that.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I should be using it within this context? Or should I be using sscanf instead?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx has good examples on how to use sscanf_s